# chemfig: order of atoms

Tags: chemfig

I want to change the order of the "OH"-group at carbon 4: the "H" should be left of the "O".

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setatomsep{4em}\setcrambond{3pt}{}{}
\chemfig{
   OH-[2,.7](-[3,0.15,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\mbox{\small\textcolor{orange}{4}})
   (
   -[1,.7](-[2,0.5]-[3,0.5]OH)
   -[0]{O}-[7,0.7]
   )
   <[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]HO)
   -[,,,,line width=3pt](-[6,0.5]OH)
   >[1,0.7](-[1,0.15,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\mbox{\small\textcolor{orange}{1}})
  -[2,.5]OH
   }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Change the beginning of your formula to `HO-[2,.7,2]`. You might want to check the `chemfig` manual for departure and arrival atoms and the optional arguments of bonds: `<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,<arrival>,<tikz>]`

Comment: You should change the order on the sixth and third carbon atom as well, looks like hydrogen is attached to the carbon (and the oxygen) at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of atoms is the order you type them in: if you type `OH` then `chemfig` uses `OH`, if you type `HO` then `chemfig` uses `HO`. Ideally you also tell `chemfig` that the bond starts at the `O`. This can be done with the optional argument of a bond:

```
<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,<arrival>,<tikz>]
```

So starting your compound with `HO-[2,.7,2]` instead of `OH-[2,.7]` will give what you want. Applying this to other OH groups, too, gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setatomsep{4em}\setcrambond{3pt}{}{}
\chemfig{
   HO-[2,.7,2](-[3,0.15,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\mbox{\small\textcolor{orange}{4}})
   (
   -[1,.7](-[2,0.5]-[3,0.5]HO)
   -[0]{O}-[7,0.7]
   )
   <[7,0.7](-[2,0.5,,2]HO)
   -[,,,,line width=3pt](-[6,0.5]OH)
   >[1,0.7](-[1,0.15,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\mbox{\small\textcolor{orange}{1}})
  -[2,.5]OH
   }

\end{document}
```