# How to write text H to left of O in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to put H to the left of O, what will be the correct syntax
Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{chemfig}

 %%% Polymer symbol
 \newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
 \def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
   \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
   \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
   \chemmove{%
     \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
        width0pt\right.$};%
     \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
        width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
 \setpolymerdelim()



 \begin{document}

 \setpolymerdelim[]
 \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
 \chemfig{[:30]-[@{left,0.65}]-[:-30](-[6]OH)-[@{right,0.75}:30]}
 \makebraces[15pt,35pt]{n}{left}{right}

 \end{document}
```

Here is the output of the above MWE
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to use `-[6,,,2]HO` instead of `-[6]OH` with `<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,<arrival>,<tikz>]` as described in the answer to this very closely related (duplicate?) question: [chemfig: order of atoms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252007/134144)

Comment: Thank you so much for your alternative solution @leandriis

Comment: @leandriis sorry, I did not see your comment when I made my answer. do you want to post it, then I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chemfig` provides this functionality out of the box. You can specify the atom you want the bond to be attached to, which is called the `arrival atom`, in the fourth optional parameter when drawing the bond, like so:

```
...(-[6,,,2]HO)...
```

Note that I've switched the order of `HO` as well, so `chemfig` draws `HO`, but we change the arrival atom to the second atom, which will still be `O`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%%% Polymer symbol
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
    \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
    \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
    \chemmove{%
        \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
            width0pt\right.$};%
        \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
            width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
\setpolymerdelim()



\begin{document}

    \setpolymerdelim[]
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
    \chemfig{[:30]-[@{left,0.65}]-[:-30](-[6,,,2]HO)-[@{right,0.75}:30]}
    \makebraces[15pt,35pt]{n}{left}{right}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple version using boxes.

[image: chemfig]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{chemfig}

 %%% Polymer symbol
 \newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
 \def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
   \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
   \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
   \chemmove{%
     \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
        width0pt\right.$};%
     \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
        width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
 \setpolymerdelim()

\newsavebox{\leftofbox}
\newlength{\widthofbox}
\def\leftof#1#2{%
    \savebox{\leftofbox}{#2}%
    \setlength{\widthofbox}{\wd\leftofbox}%
    \hskip\widthofbox
    \llap{#1#2}%
}

 \begin{document}

 \setpolymerdelim[]
 \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
 \chemfig{[:30]-[@{left,0.65}]-[:-30](-[6]\leftof{H}{O})-[@{right,0.75}:30]}
 \makebraces[15pt,35pt]{n}{left}{right}

 \end{document}
```